# Pay Per Request in Django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to implement this in django: In a video site, for every video a user want to watch he/she must pay a fee before watching the video. If it's possible, what's the best way to implement this. And after every successful payment, how can the user be redirected back to the particular video he paid for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do everything `web` with Django just like with any other webframework/weblibrary.

Probably the easiest way would be to have a user-profile, and as soon as the payment has been working out you add this video to the users "allowed" list. This makes it quite easy to show the users available videos.
The redirection thing after payment really depends on your provider, paypal and others allow you to embed their payment process into your application, and have powerful APIs to check for "incoming" payments.

Comment: paypal is not accepted in my country and for each payment that will be made, users will be redirected to the payment holder site(I'm using 2checkout) and after the payment is successful the user will be redirected back to the success url page. So the big problem now is redirecting user to the particular video page after payment.

Comment: No way to add information to sucess URL Page?

Comment: Quote from 2checkout:
When the order is completed, 2Checkout will return the buyer and the sale parameters to the URL that we specify as the approved URL in our account. This URL can also be passed in dynamically for each sale using the x_receipt_link_url parameter. https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/libraries/python/tutorial/

Comment: you still have to input your url in their page and not that a script will grab the link from where they left before paying.

Comment: What about redirecting the user to the last video he paid for when he gets back to the "main" URL of your page? So you can just route to your site's root with the fixed URL?

Comment: how will that possible? when you don't know the particular video the user wants to watch?

Comment: So is he paying for more than one video at a time?

Comment: Nope. He will only pay for one. And after watching that one, and he wants to watch another, he will have to pay.

Comment: Why not just get the one he paid from 2checkout webservice -> save to the users profile and whenever he gets back (either by redirection or just opening your 'page again) you display it to him first?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible.

What you can do is have a check on your video page for a certain receipt that you can add as an entry in the UserProfile model that you'll have for your django website.

Now this receipt will only be generated when your user goes through the complete payment path which you can handle by scripts.

And as for redirection, you can have the payment processing service redirect to your receipt token generating django view that handles the addition of the user to your whitelist for that video.